# What is the type of pranayama insisted in Patanjali Yoga sutra?

Tags: yoga-sutras, patanjali

Yoga sutras of Patanjali is most common today and is available to every reader.

It talks of 8 angas of Yoga known as Ashtanga Yoga, - Yama, Niyama, Asana, Pranayama, Pratyahara, Dharana, Dhyan and Samadhi.

In this my question is specific to Pranayama. Pranayama types are different as per Hatha yogic pradipika.

In Patanjali Yoga sutras, what is the Pranayama Patanjali insists on?

And what's the goal of Pranayama as per yoga sutras? Does it talk of kevala kumbhaka as the goal of Pranayama?